# Confused MySQL answers do not add up to same number

Tags: mysql

I have a call to get the count (s) of players at our stores, the overall total is less than the separate totals added up. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

```
SELECT (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid > 100
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS total,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 12786
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS ra,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 12801
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS mp,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 12830
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS cy,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 13389
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS ne,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 13600
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS lm,
       (SELECT
         COUNT(DISTINCT (playerid))
       FROM playerhistory
       WHERE MONTH(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 11
       AND YEAR(from_unixtime(checkouttime)) = 2018
       AND storeid = 13694
       AND howmuchplayed > 0)
       AS ch
```

Which gives the results of:

`total | ra | mp | cy | ne | lm | ch
303   | 34 | 74 | 27 | 43 | 75 | 53`

As you can see the total count is 303 but when you add up ra, mp, cy, ne, lm and ch it comes out to 306

There are no other storeids in the table:

`select distinct(storeid) from playerhistory where storeid > 100`

Results in:

`storeid
12786
12801
12830
13389
13600
13694`

Do I have a flaw in my query? Why does it not add up?

Comment: Simplify. Format. Then try again.

Comment: what do you mean "Simplify. Format" as in? (i made this query just to pull the totals to post here, the working code is a lot different)

Comment: thank you rsjaffe for fixing the layout i couldn't figure it out when i posted it(was my first post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your players are playing in / for more than 1 store. Could be one player playing for 4 stores or  a different combination like 3 players playing for 2 stores each.

Your query could only work if each player can only be assigned to exactly one store. If that isn't true the result will be inconsistent most of the times.

Comment: that thought totally slipped my mind.  thank you for showing me the elephant in the room

Comment: is there a simple way of getting the full total in mysql since the total does not account for people going to other stores, or would it be better just to do the simple math in the php script?